# how to return more than one process in one method to the main method in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

is it possible to make more than one calculation in one method and return all the values of the array to be sent again to another method that will print / display them

that is the call statement in the main method

```java
process_g(rate, hours, overtime, emp_num);
```

i will be sending the values of these variables to a method and call them again and `emp_num` is the array size.

that is the process method

```
public static double process_g(double rate[], double hours[],double overtime[], int emp_num)
 {
   double STtax = 0, FEDtax = 0, union = 0, net = 0, Tgross = 0, Agross = 0, repeat = 999;
   double[]gross = new double[emp_num];
  for(int i = 0; i < emp_num; i++)
  {
    gross[i] = (rate[i] * hours[i]) + overtime[i];
    STtax = gross[i] * 0.06;
    FEDtax = gross[i] * 0.12;
    union = gross[i] * 0.01;
    net = gross[i] - (STtax + FEDtax + union);
    Tgross = Tgross + gross[i];
    Agross = Tgross / (i+1);
  }
 }
```

after sending the array values to the main method i want to sent them to another method which will print them.

so i wrote this in the main method

```
output(emp_num, emp1, emp2, emp3, hours, rate, overtime, gross, STtax, FEDtax, union, net, Tgross, Agross);
```

all the inputs are declared and correct my only problem is to return and call the `process_g` method in the main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Define output arrays to match input arrays

If you want to work in an array-based manner, the calling method should define arrays for the outputs in addition to the arrays already defined for inputs. Pass those output arrays alongside the input arrays.

```
// Inputs
int countOfEmployees = … ;
double rate[] = … ;   // Declare and populate.
double hours[] = … ;  // Declare and populate.
…

// Outputs 
double stTax[] = new double[ countOfEmployees ] ;   // Declare, but do *not* populate. Will be populated by the method called below.
double fedTax[] = new double[ countOfEmployees ] ;  // Declare, but not populate.

this.process_g( rate , hours , … , stTax , fedTax , … ) { … }

// Report. The output arrays have now been populated by the called method.
for( int i = 0 ; i < emp_num ; i++ )
{
    String result = "Hours: " = hours[ i ] + " stTax: " + stTax[ i ] ) ;
}

// Or pass them to another method.
this.someOtherMethod( rate , hours , … , stTax , fedTax ) ;
```

By the way, it seems you forgot to include an employee identifier in your data model. In your example, we do not know which employee worked which row of input data.

## Use objects instead

Your array-based approach is common in non-OOP programming environments. But you are not leveraging the power of Java being [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

I suggest you create a class named something like `PayPeriod`. The class would have member fields for both the inputs and the results. The inputs would be passed to the constructor, for one pay period at a time. The method to calculate the result fields would be contained within the `PayPeriod` class, probably called from the constructor.

```
public class PayPeriod 
{
    // Member fields
    final double rate ;
    final double hours ;
    double stTax ;
    double fedTax ;

    public PayPeriod( double rate , double hours , … ) 
    {
        // Inputs
        this.rate = Objects.requireNonNull( rate ) ;
        this.hours = Objects.requireNonNull( hours ) ;
        …
        // Calculate results
        this.stTax = … ;
        this.fedTax = … ;
    }

}
```

Collect the `PayPeriod` objects into a list or set as you instantiate.

## `BigDecimal`

By the way, never use `double` or `Double`, or `float` / `Float`, for money. For any situation where you care about accuracy, use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html), never floating-point types. Floating-point technology [trades away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed of execution.